# error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Uri

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to update my DB `int cannot be converted to Uri` with no int value inserted

```
insertedUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().update(
                    pm2_Contract.pm2_MoviesEntry.pm2_buildMoviesUri(100),
                    locationValues,
                    "Movie_ID_test",
                    null);
```

pm2_buildMoviesUri Method that return the url:

```
public static Uri pm2_buildMoviesUri(long id) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(pm2_CONTENT_URI, id);
    }
```

also locationValues code is:

```
ContentValues locationValues = new ContentValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite `update` operation returns the count(int) of affected rows, not an `URI`. So, in the next assignment:

```
insertedUri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().update(
                pm2_Contract.pm2_MoviesEntry.pm2_buildMoviesUri(100),
                locationValues,
                "Movie_ID_test",
                null);
```

**insertedUri** contains the value of affected rows count by your DB update operation.

Comment: sure that's what I have to do without even asking, I was just w8ing for the for the authority of approval from the site, thank you and have a good day